How can I add margin (space between each box) to all my rendered items in react virtualized grid?
I use react virtualized to show some items. My problem is now how can I add margin for each box to have space between every box ?
here is a sandbox you see all boxes are bordered and have no space. How can I add space ?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-virtualized-responsive-card-grid-w-infinite-scroll-forked-8kmr8t?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx
and here is my list code
export function VirtualizedGrid<ItemType>({
  items,
  renderItem,
  itemHeight,
  itemMinWidth,
  numColumns,
  registerChild,
  onRowsRendered
}: VirtualizedGridProps<ItemType>): JSX.Element {
  const gridRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const containerRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const containerWidth = containerRef?.current?.clientWidth ?? 0;

  const windowSize = useWindowSize();

  useEffect(() => {
    gridRef.current?.recomputeGridSize();
  }, [windowSize]);

  function calculateColumnCount(width: number) {
    return Math.floor(width / itemMinWidth);
  }

  function calculateItemWidth(width: number, columnCount: number) {
    return width / columnCount;
  }

  const columnCount = numColumns ?? calculateColumnCount(containerWidth);
  const rowCount = Math.ceil(items.length / columnCount);
  const itemWidth = calculateItemWidth(containerWidth, columnCount);

  return (
    <Container ref={containerRef}>
      <WindowScroller>
        {({ height, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (
          <AutoSizer disableHeight>
            {() => {
              return (
                <Grid
                  // ref={gridRef}
                  ref={(el) => {
                    registerChild(el);
                    gridRef.current = el;
                  }}
                  autoHeight
                  columnCount={columnCount}
                  columnWidth={itemWidth}
                  width={containerWidth}
                  height={height}
                  rowCount={rowCount}
                  rowHeight={itemHeight}
                  isScrolling={isScrolling}
                  scrollTop={scrollTop}
                  onScroll={onChildScroll}
                  cellRenderer={(props: GridCellProps) => {
                    const fullProps: VirtualizedGridItemProps<ItemType> = {
                      ...props,
                      items,
                      columnCount: columnCount
                    };
                    return renderItem(fullProps);
                  }}
                />
              );
            }}
          </AutoSizer>
        )}
      </WindowScroller>
    </Container>
  );
}



Just add conditional padding based on items indexes to the Container element of your TestGridItem.tsx.
Here is Sandbox example based on your code
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { VirtualizedGridItemProps } from "./interfaces";

/**
 * Interfaces
 */

interface TestObject {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface TestGridItemProps
  extends VirtualizedGridItemProps<TestObject> {}

/**
 * Styles
 */

const GAP_BETWEEN_ITEMS = "10px";

const Container = styled.div<{
  isFirstCol: boolean;
  isLastCol: boolean;
  isFirstRow: boolean;
}>`
  display: flex;
  padding-left: ${(props) => (props.isFirstCol ? "0px" : GAP_BETWEEN_ITEMS)};
  padding-top: ${(props) => (props.isFirstRow ? "0px" : GAP_BETWEEN_ITEMS)};
`;

const Card = styled(motion.div)`
  background: #111111;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
`;

/**
 * Component
 */

export function TestGridItem({
  items,
  columnCount,
  rowIndex,
  columnIndex,
  style,
}: TestGridItemProps): JSX.Element {
  const index = rowIndex * columnCount + columnIndex;

  if (index > items.length - 1) {
    return <></>;
  }

  const isFirstCol = columnIndex === 0;
  const isLastCol = columnIndex === columnCount - 1;
  const isFirstRow = rowIndex === 0;

  return (
    <Container
      style={style}
      isFirstCol={isFirstCol}
      isLastCol={isLastCol}
      isFirstRow={isFirstRow}
    >
      <Card
        variants={{
          hidden: {
            opacity: 0,
          },
          visible: {
            opacity: 1,
          },
        }}
        initial="hidden"
        animate="visible"
      >
        {`${items[index].name} (ID: ${items[index].id})`}
      </Card>
    </Container>
  );
}



not working. It paddings the whole container but I want padding all items that there a between every item is a space

can you please recheck my edited answer with conditional padding

nice thank you very much!!
